# How to back-reference the test expression in an IF() and return it

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I need to write a `SELECT` clause that computes a complicated expression and, if its value is the empty string, it returns `NULL`, otherwise it returns the value itself.

So, in pseudo code it would be something like:

```
SELECT IF(COMPLICATED_EXPRESSION(....), '\0', NULL)
```

or

```
SELECT IF((x=COMPLICATED_EXPRESSION(....))!='', x, NULL)
```

Obviously none of the above is valid SQL.

I don't want to rewrite the expression twice:

```
SELECT IF(COMPLICATED_EXPRESSION(....), COMPLICATED_EXPRESSION(....), NULL)
```

This is going to be part of a subquery, so it's not ok to split this into two queries one creating a variable and the next one using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to write a SELECT clause that computes a complicated expression and, if its value is the empty string, it returns NULL, otherwise it returns the value itself.

Use [`NULLIF()`](http://%20I%20need%20to%20write%20a%20SELECT%20clause%20that%20computes%20a%20complicated%20expression%20and,%20if%20its%20value%20is%20the%20empty%20string,%20it%20returns%20NULL,%20otherwise%20it%20returns%20the%20value%20itself.):

```
select NULLIF(<expression>, '')
```

This returns `NULL` if the first expression matches the second; otherwise, it returns the first expression.

Comment: This wont work for OP's case though since as he says it does not return NULL it returns an empty string.

Comment: @ivan `NULLIF(x, y)` is equivalent to `IF(x = y, NULL, x)`

Comment: @ivan . . . The OP is asking for the *definition* of `NULLIF()`.